# download speed become too low with reverse proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, load-balancing

I've set up nginx reverse proxies to send requests to Apache servers, to serve each incoming request so that the static content will be handle by itself and dynamic will be sent to Apache running on same machine.

But after completing the setup, the download speed become too low and it takes long time to download the static content. What can I do to improve this?

Comment: Do you have proxy buffering enabled and to what value?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on nginx's debug log, I guess you might send the request to nginx itself that causes loops.

You should edit your question to include your nginx's configuration file.